# How to speed up this Clojure code?

Tags: regex, optimization, clojure

I am a beginner in clojure. I am trying to solve this simple [problem on codechef](https://www.codechef.com/LOCFEB16/problems/ACRONYM/) using clojure. Below is my clojure code but this code is taking too long to run and gives TimeoutException. Can someone please help me to optimize this code and make it run faster.

```
  (defn checkCase [str] 
    (let [len (count str)] 
    (and (> len 1) (re-matches #"[A-Z]+" str)))) 
  (println (count (filter checkCase (.split (read-line) " "))))
```

Note: My program is not getting timedout due to input error. On codechef input is handled automatically (probably through input redirection. Please read the question for more details)
Thank you!

Comment: Try typing some input that has one or acronyms. You might find your code actually works - it does for me.

Comment: Can you say in your question which language you chose to run it in? I assume you chose Java. You would need to test it on the command line, not from a REPL. You will need aot compilation and a main that is exported in order to turn it into a Java program.

Comment: I selected clojure! maybe you can simply tell me if there is a better way to achieve this then it would be great!

Comment: Oversimplifying: "there's no such thing as Clojure" when you are talking about runtime. Clojure runs on the JVM. As you can select Clojure then you supply source so that's good. That may not invalidate that you need to have a main that is exported and other requirements met. They should have doco for this or you can ask on their forum. See if you can find any other Clojure code that has passed. I don't think the problem is with your code being too slow!

Answer (score 1):

Most text finding exercises are exercizes in regexps, this one no different. It's usually pretty hard to find a more efficient way in whatever programming language that will outpace good regexp implementations.

In this case [re-seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-seq), [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regexps, [repetition limiting](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and the multiline regexp flag `(?m)` are your friends

```
(defn find-acronyms
  [s]
  (re-seq #"(?m)(?<=\W|^)[A-Z]+(?=\W|$)" s))

(find-acronyms "I like coding and will participate in IOI Then there is ICPC")
=> ("IOI" "ICPC")
```

Let's dissect the regex:

- `(?m)` The multiline flag: lets you match your regex over multiple lines, so no need to split into multiple strings
- `(?<=\W|^)` The match should follow a non-word character or the beginning of the (multiline) string
- `[A-Z]{2,}` Match concurrent capital letters, a minimum of 2
- `(?=\W|$)` The match should be followed by a non-word character or the end of the (multiline) string

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that wherever you run this snippet of code, it doesn't feed anything to your `read-line` invocation. Or maybe it does, but doesn't send a newline as the last thing. So it hangs waiting.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn checkCase [str]
  (let [len (count str)]
    (and (> len 1) (re-matches #"[A-Z]+" str))))

(defn answer [str]
  (println (count (filter checkCase (.split str " ")))))
```

So at the REPL:

```
=> (answer "GGG fff TTT")
;-> 2
;-> nil
```

The answer is being printed to the screen. But probably best to have your function return the answer rather than print it out:

```
(defn answer [str]
  (count (filter checkCase (.split str " "))))
```

All I have done is replaced your `(read-line)` with an argument. `(read-line)` is expecting input from `stdin` and waiting for it forever - or until a timeout happens in your case.

Comment: If you check the question from the link, The program is supposed to take input from stdin and print the answer to stdout. So I can not remove those two elements from my code completely. If there is a faster way for I/O then please explain it with an example!. Thank you

Comment: It could be that the 'main' is never executed. You would need to write a main and export it. Maybe you need to submit an actual program. I looked at a C program that took from stdin and did println to return - same as yours. Difference was it had a main. Does the code runner accept Java programs?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the slow part of your code, but if it is your could try to split up the execution and safe gard the very slow regexp part by executing it when it is necessary. I think the current version with AND already does that. If it does not you can try to do something else, like this:

```
(defn checkCase [^String str]
  (cond 
    (< (.length str) 2) 
      false  
    (re-matches #"[A-Z]+" str) 
      true
    :else
      false))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try using `re-seq` instead of spltting the string and checking every item? So you will lose the `filter`, `.split`, and additional function call. Something like this:

```
(println (count (re-seq #"\b[A-Z]{2,}?\b" (read-line))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit a Java program. You can test it on the command line before you submit it. You can but don't need to use redirection symbols (`<`,`>`). Just type the input and see that every time you do it returns the count after you have typed `enter`.

You will need aot compilation (Ahead Of Time, which means that .class files are included) and a main that is exported. Only then will it become a Java program.

Actually when they ask for a Java program they probably mean a .class file. You can run a `.class` file with the `java` program (which I imagine is what their test-runner does). Put it in a shell or batch file when testing, but just submit the `.class` file.

Comment: I submitted it as a clojure file and NOT java file so this answer is not valid

Comment: I agree. Just when I tried to submit something to help here Clojure was not in the list of languages I received back. I'll delete it sometime. Will leave for now because it represents a workaround.